# Extending jQuery Plugin default options with user's

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, closures

In the following demo: what is happening in this line of code?

```
settings = $.extend({}, defaultSettings, settings || {});
```

What is the difference between the above and this one:

```
    if(settings){
    settings = $.extend(defaultSettings, settings);
}
```

==================================

```
(function($){
    var defaultSettings = {
        mode            : 'Pencil',
        lineWidthMin    : '0',
        lineWidthMax    : '10',
        lineWidth       : '2'
    };

    $.fn.wPaint = function(settings)
    {
        settings = $.extend({}, defaultSettings, settings || {});

        return this.each(function()
        {
            var elem = $(this);

            //run some code here
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: what does this construct mean? settings || {}  = whatever is supplied to the plugin or if nothing was supplied?

Comment: It's basically to check if the user passed anything in to the function. If they didn't, an empty object is used to be merged. That line's not actually necessary, because a null/undefined third parameter isn't treated differently than `{}`.

Comment: And to answer you question about how it's different than `if(settings){` - if you don't guarantee `settings` is an object and has been extended with `defaultSettings`, you can't use it properly after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
settings = $.extend({}, defaultSettings, settings || {});
```

The jQuery **$.extend()** method copies properties from one or more objects into each other, from right to left.  In this specific example, the method is being passed three objects: `{}` (empty object), `defaultSettings` and then `settings` (or an empty object if `settings` doesn't exist).  So, going from right to left, all properties of settings will be copied into `defaultSettings` and then the result of that will be copied into the empty object (`{}`).  The upshot of all this is that properties in `settings` (which are the user's custom options) will take precedence over `defaultSettings` and then they are all copied into an empty object.  The reason for the empty object is because **$.extend()** actually modifies the first argument by reference, so passing in an empty object as the first object essentially makes a clone without modifying any object.

```
if(settings){
    settings = $.extend(defaultSettings, settings);
}
```

This does the same thing except, instead of replacing `settings` with an empty object if it doesn't exist, it simply doesn't execute the given code.

UPDATE:
Regarding `settings || {}`, this means use the settings object if it exists (technically, if it is truthy) **OR** use an empty object.  It avoid passing a value of `undefined`.

Comment: In regards to your UPDATE - passing a value of `undefined` doesn't change anything about the merged/final object, so that `settings || {}` is unnecessary

Comment: @Ian: You're correct but I'm not here to judge the efficiency of the code presented.  As per the question asked, I'm just explaining to the OP what each piece of code means/is doing, regardless of the wisdom of it.

Comment: Oh I know, I wasn't arguing, I was just adding. I just wanted to clarify that part, which you're absolutely right about. I think your whole explanation is great!

Comment: @TNguyen Thank you much, indeed! My mind knew the construct was doing something along the same line, but you explained it very beautifully! I am sure it will  help beginners like me understand special constructs!